# How do I enter Pose Mode in Blender 2.81?

Tags: pose-mode

I have a figure and added rigging.

I'm supposed to select both objects, go to auto weights and then switch over to Pose Mode.

I don't see that option. How do I pose my character?

Answer (score 1):

What most likely happened is that you have the *deforming* object controlled by the bones selected as active. Select *only* the bones, and switch to pose mode. You don't need both selected.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to select the object first and then the armature/bones. This way you should be able to see pose mode.